# efficient way to insert a unique_ptr into a map without deleting the pointer if the key already exists

Tags: c++, c++17

The easy way is obviosuly

```
std::map<int,std::unique_ptr<something>> mymap;

auto f = mymap.find(5);
std::unique_ptr<something> myptr;

if (f == mymap.end())
    mymap.insert({5, std::move(myptr)});
```

However, this doesn't look too efficient, as I have to find the key in the map twice. One to check if the key doesn't exist, and the insert function will also do the same.

If I simply use `mymap.insert({5, std::move(myptr)});` then my unique ptr (myptr) is gone if `pair.second` returns false (key already exists).

EDIT:

Apparently the answer is on C++17, with `try_emplace`, and it's already available in the compiler I'm using (vs2015) and since I'm working on a personal project, I can afford to use it.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't look efficient? Looks fine to me.

Comment: If you are worried about the complexity of `std::map::find` then perhaps you are using the wrong container? `std::unordered_map` sits on top of a hashtable, making some operations O(1) amortized instead of O(log n) - find included.

Comment: Looks almost like you want the coming in the next standard [`try_emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace)

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): You ask us a question about a solution you have and want help fixing it, but you don't tell us the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for that, Before I created this question I was looking for a try_ function, but in the wrong place (cplusplus.com)

Answer (score 6):

If you are not going to store `nullptr`s in your map then you can do it like this:

```
auto& r = mymap[5];
if ( r == nullptr )
    r = std::move(myptr);
```

Comment: That's a very interesting idea!

Answer (score 2):

The standard trick is to search for the insertion point:

```
auto f = mymap.lower_bound(5);
if ((f == mymap.end()) || mymap.key_comp()(5, f->first)) {
    mymap.insert(f, {5, std::move(myptr)}); // or mymap.emplace_hint(f, 5, std::move(myptr))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't quite understand the context but why to move anything and not emplace it?

```
std::map<int,std::unique_ptr<something>> mymap;

auto f = mymap.find(5);

if (f == mymap.end()) 
    mymap.emplace(5, std::make_unique<something>(myptr));
```

Comment: This still does the lookup twice, just as the original OP snippet.